# how can I preventDefault in this case? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, preventdefault

Somehow when I set the `preventDefault()` within the function, it wouldn't work.  I believe this is somehow a scope problem? if It is, how can I solve it though?

Can someone give me a hand?
Thanks in advance.

```
var abc = {
    save: function () {
        var $optionsRegex = this.$optionsRegex;
        $('.save-options').on('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var regex = '';

            $.each($('.input-options'), function (index) {
                var val = $(this).children('input').val();
                if (val !== "") {
                    regex += (index + "," + val + ":");
                }
            });
            return $optionsRegex.val(regex.slice(0, -1));
        });
    },
};
```

works fine if I didn't put it into an object though
this would work fine

```
$('.save-options').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var optionsRegex = '';

    $.each($('.input-options'), function (index, value) {
        var value = $(this).children('input').val();
        if (!value == "") {
            optionsRegex += (index + "," + value + ":");
        }
    });
   return $('#id_options_regex').val(optionsRegex.slice(0, -1));
});
```

Comment: instead of `e.preventDefault();` you can try `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: `!val == ""` looks fishy.

Comment: @FabianKlötzl haha you are totally right

Comment: If `$('.input-options')` is an <input> you won't get it with `.children()`, use `.find()` instead.

Comment: jQuery interprets the return value of an event handler. Are you sure, that is intended behaviour?